# Remove first child and replace with new child on pagination reactjs

Tags: reactjs, pagination

After running a search, results are displayed, in this case, 5 recipes. When I click next to display the next 5, the original results stay on page with the new ones going underneath them. Would like to have the previous ones removed and replaced with just the next results. I'm thinking about removing first child but don't know how to go about this in React.  Below is the code I currently have.

```
import './App.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from "react";
import Recipe from './components/recipes/Recipe.jsx';
import { Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';



function App() {

    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch]= useState('');
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [pagination, setPagination] = useState(0);

    const prevSearchIdRef = useRef();
    useEffect(()=>{
      prevSearchIdRef.current = query;
    });
    const prevSearch = prevSearchIdRef.current

    let currentPagination = pagination;

    const fetchRecipes = async () => {
      
    if(prevSearch !== query){
      currentPagination = 0;
      setPagination(0);
    }

    

    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=8f7859bc&app_key=f7c43e28aea5bc242e86fe0f089dda3c&from${currentPagination}&to=${pagination + 5}`)
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
    }

    const updateSearch = e => {
      setSearch(e.target.value);
      };


    const getSearch = e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setQuery(search);
      setSearch('');
    }

    const prevClick = () => {
      if(pagination === 0){
        return;
      }
      setPagination(pagination-5);
  }

  const nextClick = () => {
    
      setPagination(pagination+5);
      
  }

 
    
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchRecipes();
    }, [query, pagination]) 
    
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="Nav">NAV BAR COMPONENT HERE</div>
      
      <div className="search-container">
        <form onSubmit={getSearch} className="search-form">
          <input className="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search recipes" value={search} onChange={updateSearch} />
          <button className="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <br/>
      <h2>Your search results for "{query}"</h2>
      
      <div className="recipeList">
        {recipes?.length ? ( 
            <Row>
                {recipes !== [] && recipes.map((recipe, index) => <Col><Recipe  recipe={recipe.recipe} key={index} /></Col>)}
            </Row>
            ):(
              <div>No recipes found. Please try another search.</div>
            )
        }
      </div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={prevClick}>Prev</button>
          <button onClick={nextClick}>Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you shouldn't be looping over the recipes directly when rendering, instead generate an array that is the pagination window and then iterate over that to render

Comment: Being fairly new to React, that kind of makes sense to me. How would I go about doing what you recommend?

Comment: you need to define the number of rows each page should show. `const rows = 20`. with that you can then do something like `const paginatedRecipes = recipes.slice(pagination, rows)` and then just use this array when you go to render. I would recommend you make `pagination` be a page number rather than your **offset**. the offset is a simple calculation of page * rows. But this way you have page = 1, rows = 20, offset = 1 * 20 === 20.

Comment: Ok. that makes a lot more sense to me. I will give it a try. Would I call paginatedRecipes in the return or somewhere else?

Comment: what do you mean by `call`? you create the `paginatedRecipes` array before the return. Inside the return you should be referencing `paginatedRecipes` instead of `recipes`... Hope that helps clarify

Comment: Ok. I probably didn't ask properly but that's the answer I was looking for. Thank you very much, John.

Comment: Happy to help! if you struggle with this I can help you on a codesandbox or something to give a fuller picture :)

Comment: John, how would we go about doing that? I'm all over the place on this but do not want to give up.

Comment: [Here you go](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-montalcini-iq38d), this is a pretty simple example but should get the concepts across :)

Comment: thanks John. just received it, will now take a look at it.

Comment: Would you be able to go live on it so we could discuss what's happening in the code?

Comment: Sure, here is the live link https://codesandbox.io/live/b383a1baf9e

Comment: Were you able to finish debugging that issue?